# Javascript files aren't loading in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Ok, I may be an absolute idiot but I can't seem to figure this out... In my functions.php file I have this function that enqueues my style sheets and script files:

```
    function load_style_sheets() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/css/bootstrap.min.css', '', '','all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/bootstrap.min.js', '', array( 'jquery' ), true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/custom.js', '', array( 'jquery' ), true );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_style_sheets');
```

I intentionally have the last value of my scripts set to 'true', because I need my script to load in after the body content, however- they don't appear to be loading.
Basically what I want to happen is everytime I declare a div with the class of "ornament", my JS file runs this:

```
// add divider line ornaments
    function addLineOrnaments() {
        $(".ornament").append('<img src="img/divider-glyph.png" alt="" />');
    }
    addLineOrnaments();
```

When testing this on a static HTML site I had no problems, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in WordPress.

Comment: You're saying they aren't loading. So are they actually not loading or it's just your guess?

Comment: Just FYI, it's probably a better idea to do this with CSS...

Comment: When I look at footer with developer tools it shows the scripts are at bottom, but they're not doing anything.


I can't use CSS because, because I made the main content area into a custom widget area, and all the different potential sections of the website have been made into widgets- like this oranament file, for example, which is used as a divider line.

Comment: @Nick Jankowski: "When I look at footer with developer tools it shows the scripts are at bottom" --- so they **are** loaded, aren't they?

Comment: @zerkms That's correct. I'm sorry, I checked the footer in dev tools AFTER posting this. So I suppose a more accurate phrasing of the question is, "if my JS files are loading, why are they not doing anything?"

Comment: @Nick Jankowski: they are doing what is put to them :-)

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that Wordpress loads jQuery in 'safe' mode, where you can't use $ as a shorthand. Try using

```
        jQuery(".ornament").append('<img src="img/divider-glyph.png" alt="" />');
```

instead

Comment: Can you not just say `$ = jQuery` and just do what OP has?

Comment: I imagine you could, but Wordpress and other frameworks load jQuery  in compatibility mode by default so you can use other Javascript frameworks, some of which come bundled with Plug-ins you may want to enable. So, while it may work it could lead to problems.

Comment: really the downvote? Judging from the comments above the scripts are loaded and it's the OP's function call that isn't working. OP should also try using Firebug or Chrome developer tools...

Comment: @corneliusk I changed that and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: did you step through the code in Firebug or Chrome dev tools?

Comment: What does OP mean? I'm not familiar with term